# Tomcat persistence manager using MongoDB as a Persistence store leads problems

Tags: mongodb, tomcat, shutdown, mongo-java-driver, persistence-manager

I used Tomcat Persistence manager with MongoDB as a persistence store.I am getting lot of problems related to this.

Tomcat not going to shutdown properly. I need to kill it later.
        It showing log like this.

```
Tomcat Log::: Jun 28, 2016 6:36:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
    INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port.Stopping the Server instance.
    Jun 28, 2016 6:36:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9082"]
    Jun 28, 2016 6:36:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Jun 28, 2016 6:36:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina
    Jun 28, 2016 6:36:23 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
    INFO: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:24, serverValue:619}] to <host ip>:<port> because the underlying connection was closed.
```

After that no response.Then I manually killed that process.

MongoDB collection creating documents more than I expected(approxiamately 100 times). I took reference from these pages.

- [Tomcat Persistence manager](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html)
- [Mongo Store](https://github.com/HBRGTech/mongo-session-manager)

Can Any One help regarding these issues?

Comment: Take a thread dump to see what what threads are still running. It appears that Tomcat has shutdown properly, but any non-daemon threads still running can keep the JVM running.